# extracting plots from list and add them together to use in patchwork library

Tags: r, ggplot2, patchwork

I would like to use the `patchwork` library to combine plots. but my plots are saved in a list. Consider the code below:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)
p1 <- ggplot(mtcars) + geom_point(aes(mpg, disp))
p2 <- ggplot(mtcars) + geom_boxplot(aes(gear, disp, group = gear))

plots_list <- list(p1, p2)
```

if I use

```
patchwork::wrap_plots(plots_list )
```

The following figure will be generated in which I won't have any control over the space between plots

[image]

However, if I want to add space between plots, I need to run the code below:

```
  p1 + plot_spacer() + p2  + plot_layout(widths = c(6, -1 ,6))
```

Therefore, I looking for a way to extract plots from the list (plots_list) and then add "+" them and combine them in the form above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A second option would be to use the `design` argument, e.g. `design="A#B"` will add a spacer between your plots and of course could you do something like `paste(LETTERS[seq(length(plots_list))], collapse = "#")` to create the design string programatically.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)
p1 <- ggplot(mtcars) + geom_point(aes(mpg, disp))
p2 <- ggplot(mtcars) + geom_boxplot(aes(gear, disp, group = gear))

plots_list <- list(p1, p2)

design <- "A#B"

patchwork::wrap_plots(plots_list) + plot_layout(widths = c(6, -1, 6), design = design)
```

[image]

**UPDATE** Already guessed that you want more than two plots. Especially with multiple rows this a bit tricky and requires some work. The following is a basic approach using a custom function to create the `design` string based on the desired number of rows.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)
p1 <- ggplot(mtcars) + geom_point(aes(mpg, disp))
p2 <- ggplot(mtcars) + geom_boxplot(aes(gear, disp, group = gear))

plots_list <- list(p1, p2, p1, p2, p1)

make_design <- function(x, nrows) {
  np <- length(x)
    
  ncols <- ceiling(np / nrows)

  design <- LETTERS[seq(np)]
  if (np %% 2 == 1) design <- c(design, rep("#", nrows * ncols - np))
  
  design <- split(design, rep(seq(nrows), each = ncols))
  design <- vapply(design, paste, collapse = "#", FUN.VALUE = character(1))
  design <- paste(design, collapse = "\n")
  
  return(design)
}

design <- make_design(plots_list, 3)

patchwork::wrap_plots(plots_list) + plot_layout(widths = c(6, -1, 6), design = design)
```

[image]

```r
design <- make_design(plots_list, 2)

patchwork::wrap_plots(plots_list) + plot_layout(widths = c(6, -1, 6, -1, 6), design = design)
```

[image]

Comment: What if the number of plots is dynamic? should I every time change the design? I mean, if I allow the user to have a flexible number of plots within two columns (for example, if there are 5 plots, it would be three rows and two columns). How should it be, then?

Comment: I just added an update to create the `design` string using a small custom function  which allows to pass the desired number rows.

Answer (score 2):

Create another list and programmatically add `plot_spacer()` into the odd indices.

```r
newlist <- vector("list", 2*length(plots_list) - 1)
newlist[seq(1, 2*length(plots_list), by=2)] <- plots_list
newlist[seq(2, 2*length(plots_list)-1, by=2)] <- replicate(length(plots_list)-1, plot_spacer(), simplify = FALSE)

### final plot
widths <- sapply(newlist, function(L) if (inherits(L, "spacer")) -1 else 6)
Reduce(`+`, newlist) + plot_layout(widths = widths)
```

Comment: Thank you, how in case there are more plots, for example, 5, they will be very small. is there any way to limit the number of plots to two columns? for example if there are 5 plots the array shall be 3 rows and 2 columns?

Comment: `plot_layout(widths=widths, nrow=ceiling(length(plots_list)/3))`?

Comment: doesn't seem to be working. Here is the data for 5 plots. in fact, I want to arrange them in two plots and make the space between the columns a little bit larger: p1 <- ggplot(mtcars) + geom_point(aes(mpg, disp))
p2 <- ggplot(mtcars) + geom_boxplot(aes(gear, disp, group = gear))
p3 <- ggplot(mtcars) + geom_bar(aes(gear)) + facet_wrap(~cyl)
p4 <- ggplot(mtcars) + geom_bar(aes(carb))
p5 <- ggplot(mtcars) + geom_violin(aes(cyl, mpg, group = cyl))

plots_list <- list(P1 = p1,P2 = p2,P3 = p3, p4 = p4, p5 = p5)

Comment: I see that now, sorry. Perhaps `wrap_plots` can be used to do that, though I'm having a little difficulty getting it to "just work".